# NoMethodError in Articles#show.undefined method `article_comments_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```html
    **ARTICLE CONTROLLER**                  //controller
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
 def index
 @article=Article.all
 end
 def show
 @article=Article.find(params[:id]) 
 @comment = Comment.new
    @comment.article_id = @article.id  
 end
 def new
 @article=Article.new
 end
 def create
 @article = Article.new(article_params)
    @article.save
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
 end
 def destroy
 article=Article.find(params[:id])
    article.destroy
    redirect_to articles_path
 end
 def edit
  @article = Article.find(params[:id]) 
 end
 def update
 @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.update(article_params)
    flash.notice = "Article '#{@article.title}' Updated!"
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
 end
 def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body)
    end
end

**SHOW.HTML.ERB**            /view file

<h1><%=@article.title%></h1>
<p><%=@article.body%></p>
<br><hr>

<%= link_to "edit", edit_article_path(@article) %>|
<%= link_to "delete",article_path(@article), method: :delete,data: {confirm: "Really delete the article?"} %>|
<%= link_to "<< Back to Articles List", articles_path %>
<h3>Comments</h3>
<%= render partial: 'articles/comment', collection: @article.comments %>
<%= render partial: 'comments/form' %>

**_FORM.HTML.ERB**             //_form view
<h3>Post a Comment</h3>

<%= form_for [ @article, @comment ] do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :author_name %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :author_name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br/>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
   rake routes:
 Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
articles GET    /articles(.:format)          articles#index
         POST   /articles(.:format)          articles#create
 new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)      articles#new
edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format) articles#edit
 article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show
         PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
         PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
         DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#destroy
    root GET    /                            articles#index
comments GET    /comments(.:format)          comments#index
         POST   /comments(.:format)          comments#create
 new_comment GET    /comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
edit_comment GET    /comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
 comment GET    /comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
         PATCH  /comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
         PUT    /comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
         DELETE /comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
```

i get no articles_comments_path!
NoMethodError in Articles#show
Showing /home/manoj/ror/blogger/app/views/comments/_form.html.erb where line #3 raised:

undefined method `article_comments_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000005be3d40>:0x000000054cacc0>
app/views/comments/_form.html.erb:3:in`_app_views_comments__form_html_erb__3077497298558231225_47236640'
app/views/articles/show.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_articles_show_html_erb__4529829459036724249_48053660'

Comment: can you post your routes?

Comment: show the form.html.erb where this error occurs.

Comment: @JoelL : i posted in the snippet

Comment: the form for tag in the _form.html.erb

Comment: There is no helper method with the name `article_comments_path` in the route file you mentioned above, hence the error. You have to add routes for it to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***You are getting this error because you don't have article_comments_path helper method.*** Change your routes to this:

```
resources :articles do
  resources :comments
end
```

**OR**

If you don't want to nest routes then change your form to this:

```
<%= form_for @comment do |f| %>
  // form fields
<% end %>
```

Also in show action you can dry up your code by using [`association methods`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference)

```
def show
  @article= Article.find(params[:id])   
  @comment = @article.comments.build 
end
```