# NoMethodError in Articles#show after following step 6.4 of RoR Guide Creating a Blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to RoR and I'm trying to follow the guide at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html
I'm currently at section 6 point 4 but I'm getting stuck here.

I'm getting the following error: NoMethodError in Articles#show

```
Showing /Users/riaanvanstraaten/rubyapps/blog/app/views/articles/show.html.erb where line #12 raised:

undefined method `article_comments_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fac016d6d20>:0x007fac01c05f30>
Extracted source (around line #12):
10                   
11 <h2>Add a comment:</h2>
12 <%= form_for([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>
13  <p>
14    <%= f.label :commenter %><br>
15    <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
```

I've double checked the code from the guide but I cannot see where I am going wrong.

I've searched for some advise and followed some suggestions with no positive result.
I've one post that is very close to my problem, but the mentioned solutions does not resolve my current problem. This is the link to the similiar post: [NoMethodError in Articles#show.undefined method `article_comments_path'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574465/nomethoderror-in-articlesshow-undefined-method-article-comments-path)

Here is the code from the files used

> show.html.erb

```
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @article.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Text:</strong>
  <%= @article.text %>
</p>

<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= form_for([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :commenter %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %> |
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(@article) %>
```

> comments_controller.html.erb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end

  private
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body)
    end
end
```

> routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

    resources :articles do
        resources :commments
    end
end
```

Here is my 'rake routes' output

```
               Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                        Controller#Action
    article_commments GET    /articles/:article_id/commments(.:format)          commments#index
                      POST   /articles/:article_id/commments(.:format)          commments#create
 new_article_commment GET    /articles/:article_id/commments/new(.:format)      commments#new
edit_article_commment GET    /articles/:article_id/commments/:id/edit(.:format) commments#edit
     article_commment GET    /articles/:article_id/commments/:id(.:format)      commments#show
                      PATCH  /articles/:article_id/commments/:id(.:format)      commments#update
                      PUT    /articles/:article_id/commments/:id(.:format)      commments#update
                      DELETE /articles/:article_id/commments/:id(.:format)      commments#destroy
             articles GET    /articles(.:format)                                articles#index
                      POST   /articles(.:format)                                articles#create
          new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)                            articles#new
         edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format)                       articles#edit
              article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)                            articles#show
                      PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)                            articles#update
                      PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)                            articles#update
                      DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)                            articles#destroy
```

What's wrong? I copied and pasted the code from the website to see what I'm doing wrong, but I still cannot to resolve the issue.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in your `routes.rb`. You have 3 `m` letters in word comments instead of 2 here:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :articles do
    resources :commments
  end
end
```